# Custom font on button click android

Tags: android, onclick, android-fonts, android-imagebutton

I am making a text editor. I have a image button and what I want is that when I click that image button the editor font would change to a custom font given in assets folder.

Also when I run the app it unfortunately stops. Below is the java code.

```
    String fontPath = "fonts/PORNSA_.TTF";
    final Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    fontButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            et.setTypeface(tf);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Formatted text and hopefully clarifed the question

Comment: App  unfortunately stops as in it crashes...that's the error

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your font file name without Caps and "_" symbol?